# How to define a type which is the type of exclude 'a' from string?

Tags: typescript, types

I want to define a type like this:

```
type Response = {
   type: 'a',
   value: string
} | {
   type: ???, // any other string except 'a'
   value: number
}
```

Is it possible?

I tried:

```
type OtherStrings = Exclude<string, 'a'>
```

But which is not working as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

I guess nothing better than this is possible

```
type OtherStrings<T> = T extends 'a' ? never : string

const OtherStrings: OtherStrings<'b'> = 'b'
const OtherStrings: OtherStrings<'a'> = 'a' // err
```

PS. Instead of kinda hacks like this, you should list explicitly all the possible string options that you want to allow or disallow.

Comment: Not really a workable solution for the question. This does not work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20OtherStrings%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20'a'%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20string%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Response2%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20OtherStrings%3C'a'%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20value%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20oo%3A%20Response2%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'b'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%200%0D%0A%7D

Comment: Yeah. Its because you should pass a type parameter identical to the value you want to type check. I know its a mess, not elegant at all etc. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20OtherStrings%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20'a'%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20string%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Response2%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20OtherStrings%3CT%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20value%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20oo%3A%20Response2%3C'b'%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'b'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%200%0D%0A%7D